# Jest not mocking module when using "doMock" to avoid hoisting

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a class that creates and returns another class. I've got this:

```
const mockMethod = jest.fn();

const mockClassA = jest.fn<ClassA>(() => ({
  method: mockMethod
}));

jest.mock("../src/ClassB", () => ({
  ClassB: {
    getClassA: () => new mockClassA()
  }
}));
```

It gets caught out because of the hoisting, the `mockClassA` is undefined when jest is mocking `../src/ClassB".

I've read if you don't want hoisting, just use `doMock` instead:

> When using babel-jest, calls to mock will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block. Use this method if you want to explicitly avoid this behavior.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/next/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options

When I run with `mock`, I get `TypeError: mockClassA is not a constructor`, as mockClassA is undefined because the `mock` is hoisted above the definition for mockClassA.

When I change `mock` to `doMock`, it simply does not mock the module - it uses the real thing.

---

**Edit:** Declairing them in-line means I can't easily access the mocked methods for checking:

```
jest.mock("../src/ClassB", () => ({
  ClassB: {
    getClassA: () => ({
      method: jest.fn()
    })
  }
}));
```

Because `getClassA` is a function, it's returning a separate instance of the object with `method`.

---

**Edit 2:** Ah! Managed to inline it like so:

```
jest.mock("../src/ClassB", () => {
  const mockMethod: jest.fn();
  return {
    ClassB: {
      getClassA: () => ({
        method: mockMethod
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have 2 options here:

1. use `jest.mock`, inline the `mockClassA` and `mockMethod`, expose them in the mock and then import from '../src/ClassB'
2. use doMock, but use a dynamic `require` within your test case.

Comment: The problem with 1, is I get different instances of the mocked methods, as they're functions. Haven't been able to get option 2 to work, do you have an example? `require('../src/ClassB')` doesn't seem to affect it.